# Add Elements to array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create an empty array and add in a for loop multiple different values. Should I use append or concatenate for this? The code is nearly working.

```
values=np.array([[]])
for i in range(diff.shape[0]):
  add=np.array([[i,j,k,fScore,costMST,1]])
  values=np.append([values,add])
```

The result should like

```
[[0,...],[1,...],[2,...],...]
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could be nice

Comment: You could initialise an empty array with `np.empty` and just insert at that index, or you could use `np.h/v/dstack`.

Comment: If you're using a for loop to do anything in numpy you're doing it wrong.

Comment: You could use regular nested lists, rather than Numpy arrays too. Likely will be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use neither.  `np.append` is just another way of calling `concatenate`, one that takes 2 arguments instead of a list.  So both are relatively expensive, creating a new array with each call.  Plus it is hard to get the initial value correct, as you have probably found.

List append is the correct way to build an array.  The result will be a list or list of lists.  That can be turned into an array with `np.array` or one of the `stack` (concatenate) functions at the end.

Try:

```
values=[]
for i in range(diff.shape[0]):
  add=np.array([[i,j,k,fScore,costMST,1]])
  values.append(add)
values = np.stack(values)
```

Since `add` is 2d, this use of `stack` will make a 3d.  You might want `vstack` instead (or `np.concatenate(values, axis=0)` is the same thing).

Or try:

```
values=[]
for i in range(diff.shape[0]):
  add=[i,j,k,fScore,costMST,1]
  values.append(add)
values = np.array(values)
```

this makes a list of lists, which `np.array` turns into a 2d array.